# Interface inheriting TypeScript real world usage

Tags: typescript

I have been learning typeScript for few days where I came across with the interface implementation in typeScript but could not understand it properly can anyone explain it a bit more for me with some real world example.

Comment: Can you provide a code sample that isn't clear to you?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

An interface is just simply a declaration of an API. It defines what members/fields are available and what their types are.

In TypeScript, an interface have 2 main uses:

1. Declaring a data set structure (similar to a struct in C)
2. Declaring an API.

An interface itself has no implementation. You must implement an interface.

Suppose we have the following interface:

```
interface IEmployee {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}

let employee: IEmployee = {}; // this errors, it does not properly implement the interface

// This is ok, it implements the interface
let employee: IEmployee = {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Smith"
};
```

This is a good, we assert that we aren't missing any keys when crafting an `IEmployee` object.

Now let's take another API example, suppose we want to make something stringifiable.

```
interface IStringifiable {
    stringify(): string;
}
```

This interface declares that a single method name `stringify` must exists, it accepts no parameters, and should return a `string`.

```
class MyObject implements IStringifiable {
   ...

    public stringify(): string {
        return "...";
    }
}
```

Now we have a class that implements the `IStringifiable` interface. Why is this useful? Because interfaces in itself is a type, therefore you can accept anything that is a or implements `IStringifiable`.

```
function toString(obj: IStringifiable) {
    console.log(obj.stringify());
}
```

A lot of concepts here are part of the [Object-Oriented Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming#:%7E:text=Object%2Doriented%20programming%20(OOP),(often%20known%20as%20methods).) paradigm. So reading more on OOP make some of these concepts understandable.